# Cannot insert in database from android into localhost using php

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to store data in database which present in localhost, my android and php code seems to work fine but it doesn't writes data into database.

Here is my android doInBackground

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type= params[0];
        String name;
        String user_name;
        String user_phone;
        String user_address;
        String password;
        String login_url = "http://192.168.1.5/Sandbox/signup.php";
        String register_url = "http://192.168.1.5/Sandbox/Register.php";

        if (type.equals("login")){
            try {
                Log.d("inside", "doInBackground: ");
                password = params[2];
                name= params[1];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                Log.d("middle", "doInBackground: ");
                HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                http.setRequestMethod("POST");
                http.setDoOutput(true);
                http.setDoInput(true);
                Log.d("middle", "doInBackground: ");
                OutputStream outputstream = http.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("name"+"UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name+"UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("password"+"UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password+"UTF-8");
                Log.d("middle", "doInBackground: ");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputstream.close();

                InputStream inputstream = http.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream,"iso-8859-1"));
                result="";
                String line="";

                while ((line=bufferedreader.readLine())!=null){
                    result+=line;
                }
                bufferedreader.close();
                inputstream.close();
                http.disconnect();
                inputstream.close();

                Log.d("leaving","doInBackground: ");
                return "Registration Successful";


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

here is my php file

```
<html lang="en">
<title>LOGIN</title>
<body>
<?php
require "Conn.php";



    $name= $_POST["name"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

$mysql_qry="insert into user_table values('$name','$password')";


if (mysqli_query ($con,$mysql_qry)){
echo "Insert Success";

}
else{
    echo "ERROR!".mysqli_error($con);
    }

    $con->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

toast message says something like undefined index

and database updates to blank boxes with no text.

Comment: 127.0.0.1/Sandbox/signup.php should be the localhost url from emulator

Comment: still no success

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the `html` tags and leave the php only :

```
<?php
    require "Conn.php";

    $name= $_POST["name"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $mysql_qry="insert into user_table values('$name','$password')"

    if (mysqli_query ($con,$mysql_qry)){
    echo "Insert Success";

    }
    else{
        echo "ERROR!".mysqli_error($con);
    }

 $con->close();
?>
```

Comment: vulnerable to sql injection !! use prepare query.. !

Comment: can you please give me reference to prepare query and sql injection, Jess K Denny